# How can I use destructering in JavaScript with dataset property?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign two variables with destructering. My current attempt looks like this:

```
const { textContent, dataset.value: dataValue } = dropDown;
```

***dropDown*** is a DIV node with an data-attribute(value) and inner text.

This obviously didn't work out, I got the error message ***Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id***.
Because of this, I changed the code like this:

```
const { textContent, dataset: dataValue } = dropDown;
```

This did work better, textContent was successfully declared with the correct variable.  However, I want that the variable ***dataValue*** gets assigned with the content of the data-attribute(***dataset.value***) of the DIV node.
After running my above code, I also found out that the dataset property contains a DOMStringMap.

This is the result, the code outputs:
***{
"textContent": "Select",
"dataValue": {
"value": "none"
}
}***

How am I able to assign the content of the dataset.value to the variable dataValue directly with destructering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested objects can be destructured like this,

```js
const object = { "textContent": "Select", "dataset": { "value": "none" } };

let {textContent, dataset: {value: dataValue }} = object;
console.log(dataValue);
```

Comment: I would have preferred you to use `<div id="my-div" data-value="123">abc</div>` as  object  and `let {textContent, dataset: {value: dataValue }} = document.querySelector('#my-div')` as JS...